# Looping HTML buttons by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now, code what I have takes one index and shows the button only at that index. My question is, how can I loop this, or better what are the possibilities to loop it, so that I could get the buttons to show after let's say every two label indexes. I am pretty new to jQuery, so sorry if there's a similar question to this already.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button1').hide();
  $('.button1').eq(1).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label><button class="button1">price</button></br>
<label>2</label><button class="button1">price</button></br>
<label>3</label><button class="button1">price</button></br>
<label>4</label><button class="button1">price</button></br>
<label>5</label><button class="button1">price</button></br>
<label>6</label><button class="button1">price</button></br>
```

Comment: Sorry, loop what? What do you wanna do?

Comment: show a button after every 2 labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to note.

1. There's no `</br>`. It is `<br />`.
2. See the working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button1').hide();
  $('.button1').each(function (index) {
    if (index % 2)
      $(this).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>2</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>3</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>4</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>5</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>6</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
```

This can also be achieved using pure CSS, if you want to use CSS3 selectors.

```css
button:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label>1</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>2</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>3</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>4</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>5</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>6</label><button class="button1">price</button><br />
```

Comment: And it doesn't even have to be `<br />`. `<br>` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I `<3` XHTML. `:)`

Comment: Perfectly OK (I used to also). But, I forced myself out of that habit when HTML5 came along and it was clear (for my development path) that XML wasn't going to be huge anymore. It's fine to have it, but it's just as fine to not have it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Not exactly buddy, XHTML has the structure. So I generally use it.

Comment: thanks for the tips guys, I have no idea why I wrote it like that.  :)

Comment: @Skyhigh17 Try this and tell me, would you like to accept this?

Comment: I've had this debate a number of times. There's really nothing that self-terminating tags add to the code to improve it. In order to use them, you must know which tags they can be used on. And, if you know that, then you also know to just not close those tags. To the contrary, if you do use self-terminating tags, and you don't know where they can be used, you will wind up using them in places where they shouldn't be used. Trust me...as an IT trainer for 20+ years, self-terminating tags in non-XML applications eventually cause issues.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Not about the XHTML in general... For some reason, I have an XML parser in my eyes. Not kidding, so I generally try to align or indent things that way. So... It's a personal choice totally.

Comment: @Skyhigh17 Man, I explained the answer and gave it before the other one, this is totally unfair man.

Comment: I absolutely agree about code indentation, code capitalization and quoting of attributes, but self-terminating elements (for me) just doesn't provide any real value to the code base.

Comment: @ScottMarcus May be that stupid parser in my eyes are indenting `<br>` as block level elements? `:P`

Comment: Most editors allow you to configure the indentation rules for specific elements.

Comment: Yes, I have to figure it out.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Would you happen to know why my answer was downvoted twice? I only ask you because our JS solutions are almost identical. Not seeing any anti-patterns here.

Comment: @CarlEdwards I didn't downvote but one reason is that you didn't explain anything. That could be it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah in no way was I implying that you downvoted the solution. Only reached out being how similar our solutions were.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Yea, I just told for a safety measure, that you shouldn't think otherwise, but yea, I said you the reason too. No explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. With your advice in mind I provided an explanation.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sry man, for some reason I thought he was before you, but your answer is kind of bettter anyway so I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use css3 selectors:

```
button {
    display:none;
}
```

And then target every second one.

```
button:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    display:block;
}
```

Saves using jQuery when its not needed.

Comment: FYI OP states he wants to show the button after every second item, so it's `2n+1`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button1:nth-of-type(2n + 1)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>2</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>3</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>4</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>5</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>6</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `<button>` elements already exist in the DOM then you don't need to use any JS code at all. You can achieve this using the `:nth-child` selector of CSS, like this:

```css
.button1 { display: none; }
.button1:nth-child(2n+1) { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<label>1</label>
<button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>2</label>
<button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>3</label>
<button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>4</label>
<button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>5</label>
<button class="button1">price</button><br />
<label>6</label>
<button class="button1">price</button><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button1').hide();
  $('.button1').each(function(index){
     if(index % 2 != 0){
       $(this).show();
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>2</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>3</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>4</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>5</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>6</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
```

Comment: Why do you wanna complicate things? Also, no explanation.

Comment: `$('.button1').eq(index).show();` is crap. You can use `$(this).show();` right? jQuery selectors are costly dude.

Comment: And why no explanation, whatsoever?

Comment: @PraveenKumar updated to use $(this) I don't feel this tiny snippet needs much explaining OP can look up `%` operator to see what that does if required.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to show/hide all the buttons then you don;t even need loop here, just place following statement and you are good.

```
$(function() {
  $('button').show();
});
```

Use element selector to run your code faster.

Answer (score -1):

You could accomplish this by looping through each button via [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). From there you can determine which one to hide using the [remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator on the current button's index (which you get for free in the callback). Since you only want to show every other button, simply pass `index % 2 === 0` in your conditional.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button1').each(function(index, elem) {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>1</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>2</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>3</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>4</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>5</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
<label>6</label>
<button class="button1">price</button>
</br>
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the fast answer, this was exactly what I was looking for, sry for my bad wording

Comment: Not a problem and glad I was able to help out. Don't forget to mark this answer as correct when you're able to.